# How to get data in gridview from one table but multiple select statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In asp.net c# I am trying to return the total sum when the flag = 'D' as sumDebt and 
the total sum when the flag = 'C' as sumcredit
my code is :

```
    SqlParameter[] para = new SqlParameter[4];
    para[0] = new SqlParameter("@stat_leger", ddlACCcode.SelectedValue);
    para[1] = new SqlParameter("@branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);
    para[2] = new SqlParameter("@from", db.getDate(txtFrom.Text));
    para[3] = new SqlParameter("@to", db.getDate(txtTo.Text));

    DataTable dtreport = db.SelectCmdText("Select sum(stat_amount) as sumDebt from PostedVoucher where stat_flag ='D' and stat_leger =@stat_leger and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to UNION Select sum(stat_amount) as sumcredit from PostedVoucher where stat_flag ='C' and stat_leger =@stat_leger and branch=@branch  and stat_date between @from and @to ", para);

    GridView1.DataSource = dtreport;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

in html the grid view :

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="sumDebt">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="sumDebt" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("sumDebt").ToString()))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="sumcredit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="sumcredit" runat="server" Text='<%#string.Format("{0:0.000}",float.Parse(Eval("sumcredit").ToString()))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

the problem that in gridview it's return an error ( DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'sumcredit'.)

Comment: Did you check if your query returns anything in `dtreport` using debug ??

Comment: @feby your datatable contains only sumDebt & not sumcredit that is the reason you are getting error.

Comment: @sharique ansari  but I add UNION  to get the sumcredit  but using union not help at all  do you know a way to get   sumDebt  and sumcredit  ??

Comment: @feby use can use dataset for the same query then you will get two table. you can merge these two table then give this table as a data source

Comment: @sharique ansari  can you show me how please ?? or give me an example

Comment: @feby that is not a big deal you can do it easily, you have to create a column in 1st table and then update it from 2nd table.
main thing is i pointed where is the error.

Comment: yes I understand but the thing that not clear to me how to solve it the example will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge Table try like this:-

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select sum(stat_amount) as sumDebt from PostedVoucher where stat_flag ='D' and stat_leger =@stat_leger and branch=@branch and stat_date between @from and @to UNION Select sum(stat_amount) as sumcredit from PostedVoucher where stat_flag ='C' and stat_leger =@stat_leger and branch=@branch  and stat_date between @from and @to", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat_leger", ddlACCcode.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@branch", DDLBranch.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", db.getDate(txtFrom.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", db.getDate(txtTo.Text));
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);       


    DataTable tbl1 = dataSet.Tables[0];
    DataTable tbl2 = dataSet.Tables[1];
    tbl1.Columns.Add("sumcredit");

    for (int i = 0; i < tbl2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = tbl2.Rows[i];
        DataRow dr1 = tbl1.Rows[i];
        foreach (DataColumn v_Column in dr.Table.Columns)
        {
            if (dr1.Table.Columns.Contains("sumcredit"))
            {
                dr1["sumcredit"] = dr["sumcredit"];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @feby now tbl1 is your DataSource so write like this `GridView1.DataSource = tbl1`;

Answer (score 0):

You may use Eval's second parameter for formatting resulted string:

```
<%# Eval("sumDebt", "{0:c}")%>
```